# Angular + Firebase Delete user on logout

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm developing and application using angular 4 and firebase. In this I'm giving access to the user with a login (email and password) and as guest (using anonymous auth), but I want to delete the user if the user is a guest (anonymous auth user) when he logs out of the application.

How can I delete a user from firebase auth, not from the realtime database or the firestore database, from the auth section of firebase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to create two logout button and show using `*ngIf`. If user is logged in as anonymous you need to perform delete user rather than logout.

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

user.delete().then(function() {
  // User deleted. Redirect to login page...
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

Or you can first do a check inside your logout function and proceed `user.isAnonymous`

```
logout(){
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if(user.isAnonymous){
        user.delete().then(function() {
          // User deleted. Redirect to login page...
        }).catch(function(error) {
          // An error happened.
        });
    }else{
        //perform logout
    }
}
```

check this doc for more [info](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#delete_a_user)

(*i didn't tested code myself.*)